# Normal way of saying "I'm sure you'd agree"

Tags: traduction, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

I want to say a rough equivalent of "I'm sure you'd agree that it's important to ...".

I don't really recall hearing a French equivalent, so I've written "Je suis sûr que vous êtes d’accord que c'est important de..."

I was told that it might be more French sounding to just say "Comme il est important de..." but to me that kinda loses a bit of what I was trying to say.

Is there an equivalent that's used for this phrase?

Answer (score 8):

If you want something more idiomatic and less a word by word translation, I would suggest:

> Vous conviendrez avec moi de l'importance de...

Otherwise, if you want to keep "I'm sure you", here is a closer albeit longer one:

> Je suis sûr que vous conviendrez qu'il est important de...

Comment: Colloquially this can be shortened to *Vous conviendrez de l'importance de...* or even *Vous conviendrez de...*

Comment: @gaborous It might be shortened indeed but "avec moi" is there to convey the "I'm sure" part of the original sentence.

Comment: I can't think of a case where someone would say "Vous conviendrez" while you - yourself - disagree (basically saying "Vous conviendrez sans moi").

Comment: @BabyAzerty Indeed but the same would probably be valid in most languages. For example in English "You'd agree with me that..." is as idiomatic and common than "you'd agree that..." , "You'd agree without me that..." is definitely not.

Comment: @BabyAzerty: Assurément, _convenir_ c'est bien _venir avec_.

Comment: @mouviciel Étymologiquement, c'est vrai mais plutôt que le sens « venir avec » qui n'est pas passé en français, mieux vaut retenir les sens « aller bien avec »,  « s'accorder », « être en conformité » qui existaient déjà en latin. « Convenir avec moi » ne peut pas être considéré comme un pléonasme.

Comment: @BabyAzerty It is actually possible to do it, e.g. « Bien que je désapprouve cette sortie, vous conviendrez avec vos amis de l'heure de départ ».

Comment: @jlliagre Yes that's true, but by default, « Vous conviendrez que ... » means that the author agree with the rest of the sentence and that the agreement is requested in regards to the author (not other people), you must explicitly specify otherwise: « Vous conviendrez avec vos amis de ... ». And the sense is a bit different for me here: in the first case, it's an agreement over an opinion, in the second case it's more about an agreement over a technical detail like planning, not about an opinion.

Comment: @gaborous J'en conviens :-) !

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, the way you said it :

> Je suis sûr que vous êtes d’accord qu'il est important de

is a good way to say it. It does not sound weird at all. I'm a french canadian though, so maybe in Europe they don't say that.

Comment: I'd suggest changing to "_... vous êtes d'accord **qu'il est** important de..._" to have something more formal. [SwissFr's answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/16880/7224) is also a good proposal to avoid word-by-word translation.

Comment: That is true, I changed it.

Comment: Sounds good to a French like me :-) A little bit heavy maybe, but that's how it is. And definitely informal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a rough equivalent I'd try something like,

- *Il faut admettre que*
- *On peut voir que*
- *J'espère que nous sommes d'accord sur le fait que*

These phrases are very slightly less aggressive, I'm not comfortable with telling other people what I'm sure they must be thinking.

Comment: The first one doesn't sound less aggressive to me as it implies that anyone who does not agree cannot be reasonable.

Comment: Yes it's quite a strong statement. To me it implies that anyone who doesn't agree would be implying that I'm mistaken. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following is basically just proposing another way to say the last half of your example sentence
(i.e., “[êtes/être] **d’accord que c'est important de**..."),

which I think could also be said as “[être] **d’accord sur l’importance de**… .”

This rewording would, however, also make it easier to rephrase, perhaps a bit more diplomatically, the entire sentiment using “…**nous sommes…d’accord**…”

instead of having to tell someone directly and in no uncertain terms just how sure **you** are about how **they** think (i.e., that they surely must agree with you).
 (see ChrisW’s good answer [+1, btw], especially the third option [where both “nous” and “sur” are used] and the mention of 'agressiveness' in the last sentence).
 (In addition, using “nous” (instead of “vous”) would also avoid whatever redundancy/ambiguity issues that might/might not arise with/without the use of “avec moi.”

Since ChrisW has already proposed the totally nonaggressive use of “nous sommes” with “J'espère que nous sommes d’accord … ,” I’ll propose a few that maintain some of the presumptuousness found in your example:

> Est-ce que nous sommes d’accord sur l’importance de… ?
>
> Il semble que nous soyons d’accord sur l’importance de… .
>
> Il me semble que nous sommes d’accord sur l’importance de… .
>
> Nous sommes d’accord sur l’importance de… ./[, n'est-ce pas?]
>
> Nous sommes certainement d’accord sur l’importance de… . /[, n'est-ce
>   pas?]
>
> Nous ne pouvons qu’être d’accord sur l’importance de… . /[, n'est-ce
>   pas?]

Answer (score 1):

"Je suis sûr que vous êtes d’accord ..."  sounds weird.

I am suggesting :

> Je suis certain que vous reconnaissez l'importance de ...

[Source : Linguee.fr](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=I%27m%20sure%20you%27d%20agree%20that%20)